# Why do you need two voltage sources in a switched capacitor realisation of a continuous resitance?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors

I am learning about using switched capacitors in RC circuits to create effective resistances. 
When I run through what is happening in my head, I consider the potential difference as (V2 - V1) or V effective. Since this is the case, what is the need for two potential differences, V2 and V1. Would the circuit not be the same with a single battery of V2-V1?

[image: Bilinear switched capacitor realisation of a continuous resistance.]

Answer (score 2):

> *Would the circuit not be the same with a single battery of V2-V1?*

Yes it would but, that is missing the point of what the diagram is telling you. If you had a single battery then, that means that the equivalent resistor formed by the switched capacitor is ground referenced so, and ask yourself, how important that configuration is compared to showing a more generalized circuit that *can* be ground referenced but, can also be used as a series element.

Comment: I see, so are you saying it is drawn like this to show, like a real resistor, it doesn't matter which direction the currnet flows, the resitance will be the same? I.e. if you had V2 > V1 or V1 > V2 you would still get R from both and the diagram wouldn't show this if it only had Veff. Or is there more?

Comment: Yes, that's about it. A resistor can be a series element with other series components or it can be pulling down to ground or up to some voltage AC or DC.